# Should we create a single "imports to India" question?

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing [lots of questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india+customs-and-immigration) about importing stuff to India (42 as of now). Perhaps there should be a single community wiki question covering all of the basic questions?

Comment: You could say the same thing for questions about transiting through Schengen (mainly it seems Germany) to/from US and tagged with [tag:indian-citizens]

Comment: @BurhanKhalid And we did in fact create a single question about transiting through Schengen ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Just one for electronics would be a good idea.  It'll cover the majority of these skirting-the-law questions.

Comment: I agree. Most of the current ones are for electronics/laptops. In which case just tag as duplicate of [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10990/108). Leaves the possibility for other types of import questions which could have a different answer.

Comment: Question posted: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42418/bringing-electronics-to-india

Comment: @JonathanReez [Flimzy](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42418/bringing-electronics-to-india#comment78917_42418) duly notes that [this other question about electronics](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind) does indeed cover parts of the requirements identified by the OP. Shouldn't we use the former as a base for the CW answer?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good idea.  It can be a highly focused question like "Can I take non-duty-free items to India?".  The reason being that each OP thinks they have an original question because as we all know a smart phone is not the same thing as a laptop.  And of course two laptops is an entirely different thing than three laptops.  And two smart phones with two laptops is a completely different matter altogether!

Then flag any new questions to the canonical answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be overly broad for single questions. There are different issues and regulations applying to electronics, cars, sport gear, food, arts etc.

But it's a good idea to identify that groups and make a canonical question for the broadest set of items that would have a common answer.

The most common issues could be placed in 'india' tag wiki. The links to canonical questions would be the best solution.